# How to find the root cause of a bug in a .so library

Tags: c, debugging, jvm, shared-libraries

I wrote a `hook.so` file to intercept the JVM's call to `libc.so.6` with `LD_PRELOAD`. But when I ran some applications on JVM with the intercepted JVM, it reported the error like below:

```
Aborted (core dumped)
vim /home/hs_err_pid635.log
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb3e9cd6927, pid=635, tid=0x00007fb3baa8c700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_151-b12) (build 1.8.0_151- 8u151-b12-0ubuntu0.16.04.2-b12)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [hook.so+0x8927]  find_job+0x33
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
```

How can I locate the error code line according to the information `C  [hook.so+0x8927]  find_job+0x33`?
Thank you.

Comment: @apangin Would you like to make an answer from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build `hook.so` library with debug info included: `gcc -g` or `clang -g`.
Then run JVM with `-XX:+ShowMessageBoxOnError` option.

When JVM crashes next time, it will prompt you to attach the debugger. `gdb` will show the location in source code, local variable values etc.